# Unable to alter JSON variable within a function

Tags: javascript, json, ros

Altering a JSON variable is failing for following snippet:

```
var data = {status: ''};

rosconnection.setOnOpen(function (e) {
        data.status = 'Succeeded';
        alert('success');
});

rosconnection.setOnError(function (e) {
        data.status = 'Failed';
        alert('fail');
});
```

`data` stays empty, but the `alert` gets called within `rosconnection.setOnOpen`. The error is hard to replicate hence its used on a `ros connection`, but i am 100% certain that it enters atleast one of the functions with success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show us how you know the status didn't change so...

My bet is: there is no way you saw the alert without the `data` being changed so your code probably looks something like this:

```
var data = {status: ''};

rosconnection.setOnOpen(function (e) {
        data.status = 'Succeeded';
        alert('success');
});

rosconnection.setOnError(function (e) {
        data.status = 'Failed';
        alert('fail');
});

alert(data.status);
```

So the status was not set yet. Check it inside the callback. AJAX...
What does AJAX means? A is for async, which means it will fire sometime in the future(near or far), you can't know when and sometimes don't even if it will ever be called.

**Updated version:**

```
var data = {status: ''};

rosconnection.setOnOpen(function (e) {
        data.status = 'Succeeded';
        alert(data.status);
});

rosconnection.setOnError(function (e) {
        data.status = 'Failed';
        alert(data.status);
});
```

Comment: So basically its a timing issue?

Comment: @gdoron You may wish to describe ajax in this sense c.c

Comment: Is it possible that the `setOnError` and `setOnError` are delayed?

Comment: If i add the `alert(data.status);` as you described it actually pops up with a empty dialog but alters the `status` variable. I dont understand how this is possible?

Comment: @gdoron, i know what AJAX is, but it did not exactly make me think in that direction. But it makes sense now.

Comment: @gdoron I would say so, even if it is now apparent the user knew what it meant, it will help for future users.