# Dynamically added links not working

Tags: jquery

Im having problems trying to fire an event (alert) on my script. This is the html:

```
<div class="dynamic-form">
    <form>
      <div class="inputs"></div>
      <a href="#" id="add">ADD</a>
      <input name="submit" type="button" class="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('<div id="d' + i + '" class="fielddiv"><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /><a href="#" id="remove_question">Cancella</a><hr></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
        i++;
    });

    $('#remove_question').on("click", function(event) {
        alert('dsfsfd');
        //$('#d' + $this.attr('todel')).remove();
    });


    // here's our click function for when the forms submitted

    $('.submit').click(function(){

        var answers = [];
        $.each($('.field'), function() {
            answers.push($(this).val());
        });

        if(answers.length == 0) {
            answers = "none";
        }  

        alert(answers);

        return false;                     
    });

});
```

The remove question on click function should fire an alert but is not doing anything, not even an error, what am i doing wrong? Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6x8X/) too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: @FelixKling, you, again... :)

Comment: You are trying to bind the event handler before the element exists. That simply does not work. It's all explained in [this section of the `.on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Also note that IDs must be unique. No two elements can have the same ID.

Comment: @gdoron: :D Well... it's a common question ;)

Comment: @FelixKling, I believe this question and the question about ajax are more than 1/10 of the questions in jq tag.

Comment: @FelixKling, Here are two I answered in the past hour. [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14792335/601179). [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14791043/601179). It must be stopped somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have delegation syntax. Also, use CLASSES NOT ID's or you'll have duplicate ID's.

Working JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6x8X/2/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;

    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('<div id="d' + i + '" class="fielddiv"><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="' + i + '" /><a href="#" class="remove_question">Cancella</a><hr></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
        i++;
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remove_question", function(event) {
        alert('dsfsfd');
        //$('#d' + $this.attr('todel')).remove();
    });


    // here's our click function for when the forms submitted

    $('.submit').click(function(){

    var answers = [];
    $.each($('.field'), function() {
        answers.push($(this).val());
    });

    if(answers.length == 0) {
        answers = "none";
    }  

    alert(answers);

    return false;

    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically added elements, you need delegated event handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', '#remove_question', function(event) {
    alert('dsfsfd');
});
```

Also, with your code it would be possible to add an infinite number of anchors with the same ID, and that won't work either, as ID's should be unique.