# JQuery blocking for an asynch initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, signalr

I'm writing an AngularJS service for a SignalR hub. Here's my factory for the service:

```
.factory('gameManager', [function () { 
        $.connection.hub.start();
        var manager = $.connection.gameManager;
        return manager;
    }])
```

That code would be perfect, except that that `.start()` call is asynchronous, and the [hub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs) has not completed starting by the time the manager is returned. Basically, I want to block until the start is complete before returning the manager. The `.start()` method returns a Jquery [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, which I'm guessing is part of the answer, but I don't know how to use it without a callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick.

```
app.factory('gameManager', [function () { 
    return $.connection.hub.start().then(function() {
      return $.connection.gameManager;
    });
}])
```

Now your callback function will return a deferred/promise too, so the service consumer will need to be expecting that. Your consuming code might look something like this:

```
gameManager.then(function(gameManager) {

  // do whatever with game manager
  gameManager.doSomething();
});
```

The docs for [jquery Deferred are here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). In particular, check out [`Deferred.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/).

Note that:

> the deferred.then() method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function ... These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to the promise's .done() or .fail() callbacks, or they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks...

---

**update**:

An alternate approach (and probably the better approach - since it won't require that your consumer handle the promise) is to let the hub initialize completely, before setting up your factory, and kicking off your app controller. Something like this...

```
$.connection.hub.start().then(function() {
  app.factory('gameManager', function() {
    return $.connection.gameManager;
  });

  // ...
  // kick off the rest of the app..

});
```

Comment: So it will immediately return the promise? If the service consumer attempts to call a method on the promise before the promise is resolved, will it just wait until it resolves, or will it fail?

Comment: The service consumer would need to use the promise methods (eg. `.then()`) in order to ensure that the promise was resolved before using the manager.  An alternative would be to not define the factory, or kick off the app controller until after the hub was started.  I'll post an update with this suggestion.

Comment: These are both good suggestions, thank you! I'd rather not have my consumer code know about the promise if possible, and if I start the hub immediately I lose the lazy-loading I get from the factory. I'll mark this as the answer if I don't get any other suggestions.

Comment: If you want lazy-loading, and "loading" is an asynchronous process, then the interface of the lazy accessor (in this case, the service/factory) will also have to be asynchronous. It's inconvenient, but there's no way around it.  This is often reason enough to preload an asynchronous resource. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find what you are looking for, you will have to go with Lee's answer. Javascript is mostly single-threaded and does not allow blocking (with specific exceptions, such as alert window or synchronous ajax call).